# Can separate group by different data fields or condition?

Tags: acumatica

I have created new parameter was Document (as boolean)

[image]

if I check it the result will be as below picture (group by: INRegister.RefNbr)

[image]

or uncheck it, it will be as picture 3 (group by: INTran.InventoryID)

[image]

for example: groupDocument as picture2 and groupDetail as picture3
so what I want, if groupDocument it should obey by refnbr and if groupDetail it should be group by inventory. Yet what's wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You created a report and want different result depending the value of the checkbox ? If the checkbox is ticked, you want the result shown by picture 2 and when unticked you want the result shown by picture 3 ?

Comment: @SimonML, yes as I mention above with different group.